# Rate of convergence of moments

Tags: pr.probability, probability-distributions

If $\mu_n$ are probability measures converging weakly to a probability measure $\mu$ and we also have convergence of even moments,$$\int x^{2k} \ d\mu
_n\rightarrow c_k+O(1/n)\ ,\ \forall k\in \mathbb{N}$$ Can one conclude this rate of convergence,  $\ O(1/n)$,  holds for $\int |x|^\alpha\ d\mu_n$ with $\alpha<1$?  Are there any known conditions to get such rate of convergence?

Comment: It seems taking dirac measures $\mu_n = \delta_{1/\sqrt{n}}$ is a counterexample: The limit is $\delta_0$ but higher moments converge with a faster rate.

Comment: Oh God, I am an idiot. Thanks